# Swift download image if it exists on server

Tags: ios, image, swift, download, server

I am kinda new to swift. Could someone help me with a solution for my question.
I want to download an image from server. The problem is that not every user uploaded a profile picture (for example if he registered his self new on the app).
Now, before I download the profile picture on the App I want to check if the image exists on the server or not.
How do I do that?
Thats what I have:

```
if let imageUrl = NSURL(string: "http://tes-soft.de/AppUserImages/\(Variablen.CurrentUser)_ProfilePic.jpg") {
                let imageRequest: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imageUrl)
                let queue: NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
                NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(imageRequest, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    if data != nil {
                        self.image = UIImage(data: data)!
                        let destinationPath = documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("ProfilePic.jpg")
                        UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.image,1.0).writeToFile(destinationPath, atomically: true)
                    }
                })
            }
```

The problem here is that data is every time not nill because it sends back the whole website ( The 404 page if it doesn't exist).
It works for an existing image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I would switch over to using a NSURLSession. It gives you more options, such as background downloads, and NSURLConnection is deprecated.

For the image issue you are just checking for data in your completion handler. Since HTTP is text based, even an error is data coming back. You should be checking the response header instead to see if your request was responded to with a 404 or whatever error code your web service is returning. Then you know if you should continue with downloading the image or not.